# Answer deleted for the wrong reason?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

Ok. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40564917/1553043) of mine was deleted -- apparently for the wrong reason.

Here's the reason given:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review – dur yesterday

This is not the case: I'm not linking to pages whose text might contain the answer: I'm linking to tools. I can't copy "the essential parts of the answer" because this is not what the pages I link to contain.

My answer adds links to 2 useful tools that are not mentioned in any of the other answers -- that seem to be newer and better. This information would definitely be useful to others who end up reading that question.

Comment: You are only _linking_. That's probably the culprit.

Answer (score 14):

[No - this deletion seems warranted.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/175248)

You're linking to sites away from here, but you're not incorporating the knowledge contained in them here at all.  Whose to say that those projects won't disappear or become outdated before Stack Overflow does, and at that point, what good would those answers do?

(Also, it bears repeating that the last commit to one of those projects was a couple of years ago.  In JavaScript, that's practically *ancient*.)

I personally wouldn't disagree with this removal, given that it is just links to tools, which isn't suitable for the site.  If you want that knowledge to persist, you should explain a way to solve the problem with those tools incorporated in your answer.  You don't *need* to post the entire tool in your answer, but explaining why this particular set of libraries would help would be far better.

Comment: The accepted answer is basically "roll your own with SweetJS". Do you think this is a better answer than "use this tool which was specifically designed to solve the problem you have"?

The _most voted_ answer also links to a tool -- which is not as specific as the ones I suggested. (@cancerbero's comment: "(...) the concrete AMD-to-commonsjs transformation is not documented there.")

Comment: @tfga:  Look at this from the perspective of the moderator.  When they get a flag like that, they don't have the luxury of time to look at the *other* existing answers and evaluate yours with respect to the rest.  In context, what the moderator saw was links to tools and that's about it.  If you feel like the other answers are link-only, then feel encouraged to flag them.